# WebView anchor tag run C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL project. I am trying to display posts in a WebView using custom HTML to make hashtags clickable using an anchor tag.

An example of the HTML would be

```
<html><p>Check out </p><a>@HelloWorld</a></html>
```

I am trying to make it so when the anchor tag is clicked it runs some C# code to navigate to the page to display the tag.

```
Navigation.PushAsync(ProfilePage("helloworld"));
```

I tried looking for a way with href but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you want to redirect from webview to another page.?!

Comment: @Senthamizh Like if the webview content is `<p>Follow <a>@Joe</a><\>` I want clicking the @Joe to open a page in my app called `ProfilePage(joe);`

Comment: Ok Dan., Is that a web page or an app page.?!

Comment: @Senthamizh It is a WebView that doesn't load an actual site I create the html in the c#

Comment: I understood that Dan., What I wanna know is., on clicking that `@Joe`, what do you want your app to do.?

Comment: @Senthamizh When clicking the `@Joe` I want it to run the C# code `Navigation.PushAsync(ProfilePage("joe"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From webview you can get the value of the navigating url which you have mentioned in href or something from the below method.

```
<a href="something">@something</a> //in html

void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Cancel = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("URL received after navigated123: {0}", e.Url);
        /* do your ProfilePage(Joe) stuff here */
        Navigation.PushAsync(ProfilePage(e.Url));
    }
```

You will get that `something` in `e.Url`.
Hope at-least this helps.

Comment: What do I set href to?

Comment: Set the value which you want to receive on clicking `@Joe`

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this and where to put it?

Comment: Dude., Use this method in the cs file where you are using webview. Then pass some dummy values in the href and check it in the console.

Comment: When I click it, it says "Web page not available"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169559/discussion-between-senthamizh-and-dan).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you check out Firebase Dynamic links: https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/

This allow you to navigate users to any location within your app by clicking web links, app links, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don’t understand how to use it, I tried searching around the site but didn’t help much?